# RAD Application to manage MS SQL DB

Tags: .net, database, orm, admin

I'm searching a web (or) windows application that allow me to connect to a MSSQL DB (i prefer support for 2008) and create simple pages/forms to manage my db with some customization.

I can program in .net 4.0 and i can use MsSql Management studio, but i need something that quickly allow me to create a raw admin panel... not for final user, but for me or some other advanced user... i need some customization feature about what control show for a field...

example of feature required:
- the application read the db schema and offer me defaul "forms" to list/page records and a page to edit each
- automatically create master/details forms reading relation or FK
- allow me to specify what is the format of a field (eg. i need a TEXTAREA for a varchar(500) and i need to show it as HTML when not in editing mode)
- allow me to set if show a blob as image and to upload new image/files in a blob
- read from the schema constraints and allow me to set some limit on fields (override)
- allow to create custom form blocks with the master/details i need
etc.
- AND all this, without write/compile any code

i don't know the name of this kind of application... but i remember i've seen it some time ago...

could you suggest me some name?

Answer (score 1):

I have developed application **DBEXform** for Windows forms which is working under .Net 3.5
There is possible to connect to a database and design form and store all this to XML format.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata) with Entity Framework 4 (or Linq 2 SQL) is very quick to get data driven apps together.

As an alternative, look at [Microsoft Lightswitch](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch)

Comment: Wow, Microsoft Lightswitch seems to be very powerful. i will try the beta.